# Can't install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.0.1 from NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Can't upgrade Microsoft.ApplicationInsights from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1 from NuGet.  It complains that Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector has a constraint that requires Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 1.2.0.  (The dependency would need to be >= 1.2.0 for the dependency to be resolved.)

Specifically, the error message is:

```
Unable to resolve dependencies.
'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.0.1' is not compatible with
  'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector 1.2.0 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (= 1.2.0)',
  'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector 1.2.0 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (= 1.2.0)',
  'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web 1.1.0 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (>= 1.1.0)',
  'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.TelemetryChannel 0.17.0 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (>= 0.17.0)',
  'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer 1.2.0 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (= 1.2.0)',
  'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel 1.2.0 constraint: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (= 1.2.0)'.
```

I haven't found a workaround, and I've found almost no chatter via The Google regarding this issue.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Which exact version are you installing? There is no 2.1 stable release but there are 3 beta releases of version 2.1 of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights. Microsoft.ApplicationInsight does not depend on Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector as far as I can see. The Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector NuGet package depends on Microsoft.ApplicationInsights and is tied to a specific version.

Comment: Mea culpa.  Should have been 2.0.1.

Comment: Still a bit confused since Microsoft.ApplicationInsights does not depend on Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector. However if you have Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector 2.0.0 already installed and are trying to update to Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.0.1 that will fail since there is no Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector 2.0.1 released, so you have to stay with Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.0.0.

Comment: OK now the question has been updated. You are basically stuck since the package author did not release a Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector 2.0.1 version and the existing version is tied to a single version of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.

Comment: Ok, I'm clearly confused... Now that I'm forced to stare at the error message, I realize that I have a bunch of version 1.2 components that require ApplicationInsights 1.2.0.  I'll see if I can remove and reinstall all of those dependent packages...

Comment: And just FWIW, I can't make sense of the version numbers in the error message.  The error message seems to be telling me that I have DependencyCollection v1.2.0, but I actually have v2.0.0 installed.  Something is seriously confused.  (And, yes, it appears that the package author gave us dependencies that can't be resolved.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has updated the release notes to state that version 2.01 is not intended for web applications and to continue to use 2.00.

[Release Notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/releases/tag/v2.0.1)